# Invalid opcode error (int 0x06)

Tags: kernel

When I call a C function from main.c, which is located in a different *.c file, a runtime exception is thrown. I catch interrupt 6 (invalid opcode). I don't understand that. gcc gives no error. I checked the function many times but I don't see any mistake. Because I am studying Kernel development, there is no OS on the machine. Thank you.

Edit: I have noticed that bitwise operator does not accept a variable as an right-hand expression. When I use a value instead of `off` variable, it works. What should I do?

```
uint8_t off = OFFSET_FROM_BIT(frame);
frames[idx] |= (0x00000001 << off);
```

Comment: From my point of view, I don't see any mistake either. You have to provide some more information if you want to get answers.

Comment: Thanks. What kind of information do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This excepiton was raised becasue My bootsec.bin wrongly loaded the kernel. It loaded only 15 sectors of kernel.bin. However, the kernel.bin became 30 sectors when the last *.c file was added.